# BMP version 5 not implemented yet

Tags: c#, itext, report

I am trying to generate a pdf report using itextpdf in C#. I have imported the library

```
using iText = iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

private readonly string _logo = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("img/report.bmp");
```

I have a method to generate the pdf from data passed using a datatable

```
public string WritePDFReport(DataTable dataTable)
    {
        try
        {
            if (true)//ReportCount() > 0
            {
                var rptUrl = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper().Replace("-", "") + ".pdf";
                var rpt = Path.Combine(_rptPath, rptUrl);
                var fs = new FileStream(rpt, FileMode.Create);
                var doc = new iText.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER_LANDSCAPE, 10, 10, 10, 10);
                var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
                var p = new iText.Phrase("Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy MMM dd hh:mm:ss tt zzz"),
                                         new iText.Font(iText.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 6, iText.Font.BOLDITALIC));
                doc.Open();
                var page = doc.PageSize;
                var h = new PdfPTable(1) { TotalWidth = page.Width };
                var c = new PdfPCell(p)
                {
                    Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER,
                    VerticalAlignment = iText.Element.ALIGN_TOP,
                    HorizontalAlignment = iText.Element.ALIGN_RIGHT
                };
                h.AddCell(c);
                doc.Add(h);
                var th = new PdfPTable(4);
                var logo = iText.Image.GetInstance(_logo);
                //logo.ScaleAbsolute(100, 97);
                logo.ScaleAbsolute(79, 74);
                c = new PdfPCell(logo) { Colspan = 1, Rowspan = 3, Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER };
                th.AddCell(c);
```

I then loop through the datatable writing down the data.

At the point of adding a logo `var logo = iText.Image.GetInstance(_logo);` to the I get the below exception.

```
System.Exception: BMP version 5 not implemented yet.
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.codec.BmpImage.Process(Stream stream, Boolean noHeader)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.codec.BmpImage..ctor(Stream isp, Boolean noHeader, Int32 size)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.codec.BmpImage.GetImage(Stream isp, Boolean noHeader, Int32 size)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.codec.BmpImage.GetImage(Uri url)
   at iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Uri url)
   at iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(String filename)
   at ReportEngine.WritePDFReport(DataTable dataTable)
```

The following are the details of itext in use:
[image: itext dll details]

Comment: it is correct that BMP version 5 is not supported at iText at this point (I would advise you to update to the latest version, though, which is 5.5.13.3). I suppose you'll have to convert that file before using it with iText.

Comment: @AndréLemos Do you have a link to any spec for version 5 ? Last i know is version 4 that date back like windows 95.

Comment: looking at Wikipedia, it looks like it added ICC color profiles, and it was written by The Gimp? maybe there's some info in their code. you can search for BITMAPV5HEADER.

Comment: here we go! https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gdk-pixbuf/-/blob/master/gdk-pixbuf/io-bmp.c

Comment: and [here](https://github.com/itext/itext7/blob/develop/io/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/io/image/BmpImageHelper.java) is where the image DOES NOT happen with iText7 (stops at version 4)

Comment: some clearer code on v.5 https://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-3.3.5/docs/src/Codec.Picture.Bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

From Andre Lemos comment, and trial and error I have found an image with a bit depth of 24 doesn't throw the exception. [image: bit depth]

The earlier image had a bit depth of 32.

Thank you all.